# Get IIS binding used for current request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm hosting a ASP.NET MVC web application and I've got an IIS with two different configurations.

Configuration 1:
Two websites are configured. Both point to the same application directory and have different bindings via HTTP:

- App1 binding *:8080
- App2 binding *:8081

Configuration 2:
The server has two different IP addresses assigned. Two websites are configured. Both point to the same application directory and have different bindings via HTTP:

- App1 binding 10.0.0.1:80
- App2 binding 10.0.0.2:80

Now I can call the same application via different IPs or ports. Is there a way to determine in the code which binding has been used for a specific request?

Comment: Use the `Host:` header in the Request, also `Request.Url.Port`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to get the server's IP by using C# http client. I suggest you could consider using below codes:

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

According MSFT [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)):

> Returns the server address on which the request came in. This is important on computers where there can be multiple IP addresses bound to the computer, and you want to find out which address the request used.